# gradle build operations failed

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am getting these errors. No problems in my coding in the main activity and XML files, but I am still getting these

I tried rebuilding and creating a new project with the same code, but I still get these issues.

[image]

Comment: Welcome, Please do not give images for errors, copy the errors and post them as code.  This allows us to copy and search for solutions.  Also show your gradle code.